# сервер не может принять данные в json

Tags: javascript

```
const dataToSend = {"_id":"lfg","email": "hey@mail.com", "password": "101010"};
fetch ('http://localhost:5000/auth/registration',{
    method:'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
}).then((response) => response.json())
```

На сервер приходят следующие данные:

```
{}
```

Код приема данных на сервере:

```
async registration(req,res)
{
    console.log(req.body)
    try
    {

        const {_id,email,password} = req.body
        const candidate = await User.findOne({_id})
        if(candidate){
            return res.status(400).json({message:"Такой юзернейм занят"})
        }
        const hash_crypt = await bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 7);
        
        
        const user = new User({_id,email,password:hash_crypt})
        
        
        await user.save()
        
        
        return res.json({message:"Успешная регистрация!"})
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(400).json({message:"Server error! "})
    }
}
```

Если отправлять через postman, то все работает.

Comment: Content-Type забыли указать?

Comment: когда я указываю content-type в headers, то запрос просто не отправляется. (точнее отправляется, но на сервер ничего не приходит)

Comment: Стоит заглянуть в заголовки обоих запросов (через постмана и нет) и найти разницу :)